# VBA ADODB connection to Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, vba, odbc, connection-string

i am trying to connect to an Oracle database with ADODB.

Following is my code:

```
Sub TestOracle()

Dim cs As String
Dim dbConn As Object, dbCMD As Object

Set dbConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set dbCMD = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

cs = "SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.xxx.x.xx)(PORT=1521))" & _
      "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)));" & ";SERVER=dbserver" & _
        "uid=testing_bibi;pwd=testing;"

dbConn.ConnectionString = cs
dbConn.Open
dbCMD.ActiveConnection = dbConn

'########################
dbCMD.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE streets(id INT, direction CHAR(1), A VARCHAR(255), B VARCHAR(255), d INT, PRIMARY KEY (id, direction));"
dbCMD.Execute

dbConn.Close
Set dbConn = Nothing

End Sub
```

However i keep getting the following error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no
>   default driver specified

I have oracle client installed, and the ODBC driver as well.

After adding `dbConn.provider = "OraOLEDB.Oracle"` just before opening the connection, the error changed to:

> ORA-12560: TNS: protocol adapter error

I am hoping for minimal setup for later deployment.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You must define the provider, e.g. `dbConn.provider = "OraOLEDB.Oracle"` in order to use it. Oracle Instant Client does not include any ODBC or OLE DB drivers, you have to install them separately.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thank you for your reply! I added dbConn.provider = "OraOLEDB.Oracle" before opening the connection, the error now changed. The ODBC driver is also installed.